# Why I can't validate users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am developing chat plugin and there are two types users: Operators and visitors. However I can NOT succeed to add users.

Here is my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    // By default, make all data private unless specified otherwise.
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    // Only operators or user itself can update their data
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && ($user_id === auth.user_id || auth.operator === true)",
        ".write": "auth != null && ($user_id === auth.user_id || auth.operator === true)",
        ".validate": "($user_id === newData.child('user_id').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'type', 'status']))"
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

I got those log messages while adding user into Firebase DB in chat console:

```
Authenticated successfully with payload: Object {user_id: 112, is_operator: true}
Auth expires at: Thu Aug 15 2013 20:12:22 GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
FIREBASE: Attempt to write {"type":"operator","name":"op","user_id":112} to /users/operators/112 with auth={"user_id":112,"is_operator":true}
FIREBASE:   /:.write: "auth != null"
FIREBASE:       => true
FIREBASE:   /users/operators:.validate: "($user_id === newData.child('user_id').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'type', 'status']))"
FIREBASE:       => false
FIREBASE: Validation failed.
FIREBASE: Write was denied.
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /users/operators/112 failed: permission_denied
(!) ERROR: Error: PERMISSION_DENIED :: auth() function while creating user
```

How can I solve this issue?

## SOLUTION

I was wrong with `$user_id`. It should be `auth.user_id` in ".validate" part:

```
".validate": "(auth.user_id === newData.child('user_id').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'type', 'status']))"
```

Comment: In your authentication token, it appears that the `user_id` is an integer, but all Firebase child keys are strings. As a result, `$user_id` will never match the integer `112`. Try modifying the value of `user_id` to be a string in either your token generation or in your rules (`$user_id === '' + auth.user_id`) and see if that helps.

Comment: As a side note, only *one* .write rule has to evaluate to true for the write to succeed.  That means that the .write (and .read) rule you have under "$user_id" are meaningless, since any authenticated user will already be allowed to write there since the "auth != null" rule at the root will have evaluated to true.  You'll likely want to just remove that rule at the root.

Comment: @RobDiMarco Yes. It works as well! Is it really necessary? What about my solution? I have edited the question.

Comment: @dino Glad you got it working! Can you clarify your last question?

Comment: How do you get those log messages? I find it really frustrating writing security rules, when I can't debug and see values.

Comment: @henrikstroem I used [custom authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/custom.html) and you will want to set "debug" variable as true while generating secure token (check: ["Generating a Secure Token"](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/simple-login/custom.html#section-rest-tokens-without-helpers) part on the same page). Then all logs will be displayed on your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user_id` is wrong. It should be `auth.user_id` in the `".validate"` part:

```
".validate": "(auth.user_id === newData.child('user_id').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'type', 'status']))"
```